# How to compute the discrete Fourier transform of f(x) = 1?

Tags: fourier-transform

I am learning about the discrete Fourier transform in the context of digital image processing and not in the context of complex analysis so I might have some slightly different notation/formulas.

Our professor has told us that in the 1D discrete case:

$$\mathcal{F}(1) = \delta(u)$$

if you use the formula:

$$\mathcal{F}(f(t)) = \sum_{t=0}^{M-1}f(t)*e^{-i 2 \pi ut/M}$$

Where $\delta(u)$ is the 1D discrete impulse function defined as:

$$
\delta(u) = 
\left\{
    \begin{array}{lr}
        1, & \text{if } u =0\\
        0, & \text{if } u\neq 0
    \end{array}
\right\} 
$$

I understand that the inverse discrete Fourier transform of $\delta(u)$ is $f(t)=1$ but I seem to be having trouble showing it the other way around. Here is what I have so far.

$$\mathcal{F}(1) = \sum_{t=0}^{M-1} e^{-i2\pi ut/M} = \sum_{t=0}^{M-1} (e^{-i2\pi })^{ut/M}$$

If $u \neq 0$ then each term is equal to 0 because $e^{-i2 \pi}$ is always 0 by Euler's identity.

If $u=0$ then each term in the sum is just 1 so the total sum is equivalent to $M$ instead of $1$. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: $e^{-i 2\pi }=1 \neq 0$.

Comment: First off, $e^{i2\pi}=1$, not $0$. Second, the inverse discrete Fourier transform has a normalization you are missing.

Comment: The n-th Fourier coefficient is $\delta (n)$ for $n\ge 0$. Hence the Fourier series is just the term with $n=0$, i.e. it is equal to $1$.

Comment: What's going wrong is that your formulas for the Fourier transform and its inverse are simply wrong. There must be a $\frac1M$ somewhere, or a $\frac1{\sqrt M}$ in a few places...